# Getting the "Solarium @version is too old" error after upgrade

Tags: search, 9, upgrading

I recently updated a Drupal 9.3 site to Drupal 9.5 and most of the contributed modules were updated to the latest version that supports both 9 and 10 in view of an upcoming Drupal 10 upgrade.

On the status report page, I am getting this error.

> Solarium @version is too old!

How do we rectify this error? The Solr search module is locking Solarium to an old version and we might need to force an upgrade on this. Is there a better way to do this?

More details of the composer.lock file with solarium set to 6.3.3

```
{
        "name": "drupal/search_api_solr",
        "version": "4.3.1",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://git.drupalcode.org/project/search_api_solr.git",
            "reference": "4.3.1"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/search_api_solr-4.3.1.zip",
            "reference": "4.3.1",
            "shasum": "002061b1160df5da5d13eea6f3a4c50f8008b157"
        },
        "require": {
            "composer-runtime-api": ">=2.0",
            "composer/semver": "^1.0|^3.0",
            "consolidation/annotated-command": "^2.12|^4.1",
            "drupal/core": "^9.3 || ^10.0",
            "drupal/search_api": "~1.30",
            "ext-dom": "*",
            "ext-json": "*",
            "ext-simplexml": "*",
            "laminas/laminas-stdlib": "^3.2",
            "maennchen/zipstream-php": "^2.2.1|^3.0.2",
            "solarium/solarium": "^6.3.3"
        },
```

Comment: The entire message template is: `Solarium @version is too old! Version required: @required`. Please add to the Question the entire error. In addition I think we would need to see the composer.json file to actually form an answer. We don't know what versions you have at this time or what you mean by "Solr search module is locking". Are you typing Composer commands that are not having the desired effect? If so, which commands (precisely), and what is their output?

Comment: Added the versions in the lock file to the question description

Comment: You have an outdated version of search_api_solr. The current version (4.3.2) uses Solarium 6.3.5, which is the latest

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a Drupal 9 with version 4.3.1 of search_api_solr, because version 4.3.2 is no longer compatible with D9 but only: ^10.1 || ^11.0

So I've been using version 4.2.12 while waiting to upgrade to D10.

```
composer require 'drupal/search_api_solr:4.2.12' -W
```

Do not forget the "-W" for get the Downgrading solarium/solarium works (6.x-dev b785b8b => 6.3.1)

And I no longer get the error in the dashboard